# Perl script call from Windows Batch file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a perl script which needs to be called from Windows batch file. Batch file script reads text file and pass the parameters to perl script. Now one of the argument is "User Input". Now if i give double quotes in text file the following error comes
`Could not open  : No such file or directory at perl_script.pl at Line 10`
code is  (echo the input and its showing as User Input on command prompt)
`echo %INPUT%

 perl perl_script.pl %INPUT%`
Now if i give single quotes then the perl_script gets only User (Input is truncated)
Please suggest the best way to handle this

Comment: Inside the perl script, you could improve the error message to tell you what Perl *thinks* the filename was: `open ... or die qq(Could not open "$filename: $!")`. You can also dump all command line arguments like `say "[$_]" for @ARGV`, which enclosed each argument in brackets.

Comment: Please post the batch script and the perl program.  Tough to tell what's going on otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo %INPUT%
perl perl_script.pl "%INPUT%"
```